# using immediately invoked function expression(IIFE)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

This code snippet works perfectly fine

```
const foo = 2;
(function (){
    console.log(foo);
})()
```

Now I added a variable `foo` which is a function,
But the following code snippet doesn't work,

```
const foo = function(){ return "foo" }
(function (){
    console.log("aa");
})()
```

This throws error: `TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function`

However, moving the function object within the scope of IIFE works fine (obviously),

```
(function () {
    const foo = function () { return "foo" }
    console.log(foo())
})()
```

Node version(s): v12.12 / v10.16

**Questions**:

Is this the only way when working with IIFE ?

What exactly is happening with second snippet?

Comment: You forgot a semicolon, and `(` on the next line following a function expression is legal syntax, so it's interpreted as the function being called with the content of what's inside that next `(`

Comment: oh, got it now. :) Thanks