# show/hide an element JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Button can show, but can't hide an element after showing.  Could you tell me where i'm wrong?

```js
document.querySelector('.btn1').onclick = function(e) {
  let a = document.querySelector('.btn1content')
  if (a.style.display = ('none')) {
    a.style.display = ('block')
  } else {
    a.style.display = ('none')
  }
}
```

```css
.btn1content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn1" BUTTON</button>
<p class="btn1content">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: In your `if/else` you are using the assignment operator `=` and not equals to. Try `if(a.style.display == ('none')) {...}`. For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators

Comment: 1) first `=` should be `==` - 2) initial state will be `""` and not `"none"`, take that into account or use `getComputedStyle`

Comment: Why all those unnecessary `( )`? And why no semicolons?

Comment: Change `class="btn1"BUTTON` to `class="btn1">BUTTON`, change `a.style.display = ('none')` to this `a.style.display === 'none'`

Comment: @Andreas: Agreed on the parens, but semicolons are a matter of personal style (some style guides such as https://standardjs.com/ don't use them either)

Comment: It's not a matter of _personal style_. There are defined rules when a semicolon is added by ASI. And that can mess up your script quite easily... [using immediately invoked function expression(IIFE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59208059/using-immediately-invoked-function-expressioniife)

Comment: @CherryDT I would recommend always use semicolons as not using them can lead to bugs.

Comment: @Andreas It is, the problem you mentioned can be handled by the style guide as well by inserting a semicolon _before_ such a line, see https://standardjs.com/rules.html#semicolons

Comment: @RobertRocha only if you don't use a proper linter.

Comment: @CherryDT a dev shouldn't rely on a linter, using semicolons is elementary and is probably one of the first things devs are taught when writing statements.

Comment: Well if a dev shouldn't rely on a linter, then the language shouldn't allow mistakes like the `=` in this question either... But it does. And it has ASI, so it's obviously fine to use that functionality. As the link I shared (and the pages linked from there) shows, it's a matter of opinion and style, and there are many companies and projects using a style that doesn't use semicolons (npm, GitHub, MongoDB, Express, to name a few). But I don't want want to derail this further, I am fine to agree to disagree, I just wanted to show there are different perspectives to this and not one "right" way

Answer (score 1):

you are not closing button tag. Try this

```
<button class="btn1">BUTTON</button>
<p class="btn1content">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

jQuery will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            document.querySelector('.btn1').onclick = function (e) {
                let a = document.querySelector('.btn1content')
                if (a.style.display == ('none')) {//there will ==
                    a.style.display = ('block')
                } else {
                    a.style.display = ('none')
                }
            }
            
        });
```

Comment: This solves 2 of 3 issues - initial style will be `""` so the first time will need two clicks to show the button

Comment: @CherryDT initial style will be display none as mentioned in css

Comment: No, it won't be because it comes from a CSS rule and not a style directly applied to the element. The initial _computed_ style will be `"none"`, but this code doesn't use `getComputedStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button class="btn1">BUTTON</button>
<p class="btn1content">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn1', function(){
    $('.btn1content').toggle()
})
```

Note - No need to change any CSS